# How to add HTML Code by creating column using with material table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a problem by creating column, maybe you have a solution. I will show my code as below:

```
columns = [{ columnDef: 'position', header: 'No.',    cell: (element: any) => `${element.position}` },
{ columnDef: 'name',     header: 'Name',   cell: (element: any) => `${element.name}`     },
{ columnDef: 'weight',   header: 'Weight', cell: (element: any) => `${element.weight}`   },
{ columnDef: 'symbol',   header: 'Symbol', cell: (element: any) => `${element.symbol}`   },
{ columnDef: 'symbols',   header: 'Symbols', cell: (element: any) => '${<mat-icon matTooltip="">more_horiz</mat-icon>}'   },];
```

At the last line, I just want to insert Material Icons for every column, which is created dynamically. I have tried for many times, but unfortunately my try were not successful.

Maybe you can give me some input.

Comment: Have you tried string without `${}`?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use a font awesome instead of mat component for that situation.

```
{ columnDef: 'symbols',   header: 'Symbols', cell: (element: any) => '<i class="fa fa-'${element.icon}'"></i>}'   }
```

or if icon is not dynamic simply use:

```
{ columnDef: 'symbols',   header: 'Symbols', cell: (element: any) => '<i class="fa fa-your-icon"></i>}'   }
```